# Filtrar una consulta mediante opcion seleccionada en INPUT SELECT

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy queriendo filtrar consultas mediante lo que seleccione en un input SELECT, pues necesito hacer consultas mediante diferentes opciones (CEDULA, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, EDAD, ETC...) Me recomendaron usar el `OR` para eso, pero no es justo lo que necesito.

Se me ocurria (No se si es posible y por eso escribo esto) que al seleccionar la opcion, y ejecutar la busqueda mediante un IF me tome lo que seleccione y ejecute la busqueda bajo ese parametro, no se si es posible (Y si lo es no se hacerlo, agradeceria si me ayudan)

Les dejo el codigo que tengo actualmente.

```
<?php
    $TIPO_BUSQUEDA = $_POST["TIPO_BUSQUEDA"];
    function ejecuta_consulta($labusqueda)
    {
        include("conexiond.php");

        $conexion= mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Fallo al conectar con la base de datos";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die("No se encuentra la base de datos.");


        $consulta = "SELECT datosbasicos.CED_PAC,datosbasicos.NOM_PAC,datosbasicos.APE_PAC,datosbasicos.SEX_PAC,datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.ALT_PAC,datosmedicos.PESO_PAC,datosmedicos.FECHA,datosmedicos.TIPO_CONSULTA,datosmedicos.SINTOMAS,datosmedicos.OBSERV,datosmedicos.HIS_PAC,datosmedicos.MEDI_PAC,datosmedicos.OPERADO,datosmedicos.ALERGIAS FROM datosbasicos INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.CED_PAC=datosmedicos.CED_PAC WHERE datosbasicos.NOM_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%' OR datosmedicos.FECHA LIKE '%$labusqueda%'  ";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        $filas = array(); // Crea la variable $filas y se le asigna un array vacío
        // (Si la consulta no devuelve ningún resultado, la función por lo menos va a retornar un array vacío)

        while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $filas[] = $fila; // Añade el array $fila al final de $filas
        }

        mysqli_close($conexion);

        return $filas; // Devuelve el array $filas
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sistema de historias médicas - Dr. Darling Davila</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        $mibusqueda=$_GET["buscar"];

        $mipag=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];

        if ($mibusqueda!=null) {
            $pacientes = ejecuta_consulta($mibusqueda);
    ?>

        <div id="main-container">
        <img src='imagenes/header.png' class='img'>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Codigo Consulta</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Cedula</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Sexo</th>
                        <th>Altura</th>
                        <th>Peso</th>
                        <th>Sintomas</th>
                        <th>Observaciones</th>
                        <th>Tipo de consulta</th>
                        <th>Medicamentos actuales</th>
                        <th>Alergias</th>
                        <th>Operado</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    // Si la variable $pacientes esta definida y no está vacía
                    if (isset($pacientes) && !empty($pacientes)) {
                        // Recorre cada $paciente dentro del array $pacientes
                        foreach ($pacientes as $paciente) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['COD_CONSULTA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['FECHA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['CED_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['NOM_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['APE_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['SEX_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['ALT_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['PESO_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['SINTOMAS'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['OBSERV'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['TIPO_CONSULTA'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['MEDI_PAC'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['ALERGIAS'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $paciente['OPERADO'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    } ?>
                </tbody>
        </div>
    <?php
        } else {
            echo("<form action='". $mipag . "' method='GET'>
                <img src='imagenes/header.png'>
                    <h2>Busqueda de paciente</h2>
                    <div class='contenedor'>
                    <select name='TIPO_BUSQUEDA' class='input-100 text-center col-md-12'>
                        <option value='Cedula' selected='selected' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Cedula'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Cedula</option>
                        <option value='Edad' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Edad'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Edad</option>
                        <option value='Nombre' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Nombre'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ? >Nombre</option>
                        <option value='Fecha' <?PHP if($TIPO_BUSQUEDA=='Fecha'){ echo 'selected='selected'; } ?> Fecha</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type='text' name='buscar' class='input-100 text-center inline-block col-md-6 btn-enviar espacio-arriba'></label>

                    <input type='submit' name='enviando' value='Consulta' class='text-center inline-block col-md-12 espacio-arriba btn-enviar'>
                </div>
                </form>");
        }
     ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por favor revisa la concatenaciones de php en el echo al final del archivo, estas abriendo etiquetas php en vez de usar la concatenacion

Comment: ¿Será que no es posible hacer lo que quiero? que nadie responder jeje.

Comment: ¿La búsqueda seria sobre un `campo` a la vez, es decir, el `campo` elegido en el `select`?

Comment: Así es Cesar, si por ejemplo selecciono "Nombre" que solo me permita buscar mediante el nombre, de lo contrario que no me arroje nada.

Answer (score 1):

Sería cuestión de construir la instrucción SQL en dos partes:

#### 1ª parte:

Construyes la instrucción hasta el `WHERE`:

```
$consulta = "SELECT datosbasicos.CED_PAC, datosbasicos.NOM_PAC, datosbasicos.APE_PAC, datosbasicos.SEX_PAC, 
datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA, datosmedicos.ALT_PAC, datosmedicos.PESO_PAC, datosmedicos.FECHA, 
datosmedicos.TIPO_CONSULTA, datosmedicos.SINTOMAS, datosmedicos.OBSERV, datosmedicos.HIS_PAC, 
datosmedicos.MEDI_PAC, datosmedicos.OPERADO, datosmedicos.ALERGIAS 
FROM datosbasicos 
INNER JOIN datosmedicos ON datosbasicos.CED_PAC=datosmedicos.CED_PAC WHERE ";
```

#### 2ª parte:

La 2ª parte sería dinámica, dependería del elemento que haya sido seleccionado, en base a eso completas la consulta.

Si tus select tiene las etiquetas `name` siguientes: `nom_pac, ced_pac, cod_consulta, fecha` tendrías que evaluar cuál de esos elementos ha sido pasado en el _POST.

Por otra parte, si sólo quieres que filtre por un elemento, en el código donde se encuentran los select deberías crear un código que desactive los demás select al escoger cualquier otro. De otro modo el código funcionará, pero no lo tendrás bajo estricto control.

Ejemplo:

```
//Variable booleana para saber si debe ejecutarse la consulta.
$bolEjecutar=true;

if ($_POST["nom_pac"])
{
    $consulta .="datosbasicos.NOM_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%'";

} elseif ($_POST["ced_pac"]) {

    $consulta .="datosbasicos.CED_PAC LIKE '%$labusqueda%'";

} elseif ($_POST["cod_consulta"]){

    $consulta .="datosmedicos.COD_CONSULTA LIKE '%$labusqueda%'";

}elseif ($_POST["fecha"]){

    $consulta .="datosmedicos.FECHA LIKE '%$labusqueda%'";

}else{

    //Esta condición se cumplirá cuando ningún select haya sido elegido
    //Establecemos la variable a false para que no se ejecute la consulta en ese caso
    $bolEjecutar=false;

}


if ($bolEjecutar)
{
     //Se ejecuta la consulta y se leen los datos
}else{
     //No se ejecuta la consulta porque ningún select fue escogido
}
```

De este modo la consulta quedaría con el criterio que exista en el select solamente.

Luego la ejecutas.

> Nota: La consulta creada de esta manera es vulnerable a la Inyección
>   SQL. Se recomienda usar consultas preparadas.